# How to get the main element value using xslt 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

How can I get the value of `Header` main element, "AMEX,AMEX"?
Below is my xml which contains header and the value AMEX,AMEX. I want to fetch the "AMEX,AMEX" value to display it in xsl:fo table cell.

**xml**

```
<Documents>
 <Document>
<PackingNote>
  <Header>AMEX, AMEX<CustomerDetail>Adeel/000004</CustomerDetail><Despatchdate>09/05/2019</Despatchdate><OrderNumber>000534</OrderNumber><OrderNumberBatch>000534-1</OrderNumberBatch></Header>
  <Header>AMEX, AMEX<CustomerDetail>Adeel/000004</CustomerDetail><Despatchdate>09/05/2019</Despatchdate><OrderNumber>000534</OrderNumber><OrderNumberBatch>000534-2</OrderNumberBatch></Header>
  <Lines>
    <Line>
      <ProductName>Kid-Sweater-Winter Aqua</ProductName>
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <Price>£15.00</Price>
      <Size>Small/Slim Fit</Size>
      <ReasonCode />
      <ReturnQty />
      <Fit>Fit </Fit>
    </Line>
  </Lines>
  <PackedBy>
    <SubTotal>£30</SubTotal>
    <Shipping>£2.00</Shipping>
    <Total>£32</Total>
  </PackedBy>
</PackingNote>
  </Document>
</Documents>
```

**xslt**

```xml
<xsl:template match="Header">
<!-- Title -->
<fo:table table-width="27.5cm" table-height="2cm">
  <fo:table-column column-width="5.5cm" />
  <fo:table-column column-width="3.5cm" />
  <fo:table-column column-width="14.5cm" />
  <fo:table-column column-width="4cm" />
  <fo:table-body>
    <fo:table-row border-width="0mm">
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
          <fo:table-column column-width="5cm" />
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row />
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" padding-top="1.2cm">
          <fo:table-column column-width="3.5cm" />
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block text-align="center" padding-top="0.3cm">

                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border-width="0mm">
        <fo:table table-layout="auto" font-family="Calibri" table-width="14.5cm">
          <fo:table-column column-width="5.1cm" />
          <fo:table-column column-width="3.9cm" />
          <fo:table-column column-width="2.5cm" />
          <fo:table-column column-width="2.8cm" />
          <fo:table-header text-align="left" border-width="0mm">
            <fo:table-row height="2em" border="inherit" background-color="#D9D9D9" font-family="Arial">
              <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" padding-left="0.2cm" border-width="1px" border-style="solid">
                <fo:block font-size="11pt" text-align="left" >
                  <fo:inline>Customer Name/No</fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border-width="1px" border-style="solid">
                <fo:block font-size="11pt" text-align="left" >
                  <fo:inline>Payment Method</fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border-width="1px" border-style="solid">
                <fo:block font-size="11pt" text-align="center" >
                  <fo:inline>Despatch Date</fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border-width="1px" border-style="solid">
                <fo:block font-size="11pt" text-align="center" >
                  <fo:inline>Order No.</fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-header>
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row border-width="4px" border-style="solid" height="2em" font-family="Segoe UI">
              <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.5mm" padding-left="0.2cm" border-width="1px" border-style="solid">
                <fo:block font-size="11pt" text-align="left">
                  <xsl:value-of select="CustomerDetail" />
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell padding-left="0.1cm" padding-bottom="0.5mm" padding-right="0.5cm" border-width="1px" border-style="solid">
                <fo:block font-size="11pt" text-align="left">
       <xsl:value-of select="Header" />
    </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell padding-left="0.8mm" padding-bottom="0.5mm" padding-right="0.5cm" border-width="1px" border-style="solid">
                <fo:block font-size="11pt" text-align="center">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Despatchdate" />
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell padding-left="0.1cm" padding-bottom="0.5mm" padding-right="0.5cm" border-width="1px" border-style="solid">
                <fo:block font-size="11pt" text-align="center">
                  <xsl:value-of select="OrderNumber" />
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="1mm">
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
          <fo:table-column column-width="4cm" />
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block text-align="center" padding-top="0.3cm">

                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

**desired output**

```
first header value 'AMEX,AMEX'
```

Comment: What is the question? How to query XML? Or how to write an XSLT transform? In the second case why post the SQL query at all?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to fetch the value of AMEX,AMEX using xslt. I have posted the sql query to explain that how i get the amex amex value using stuff.

Comment: That's not relevant to the question and only causes confusion. Even talking about STUFF is wrong - stuff doesn't concatenate anything. What you posted is the XML Path string concatenation query. You could (*should*) remove *any* reference to SQL Server and the tag, still get the same answer.

Comment: As for `i want to fetch the value of AMEX,AMEX using xslt` XSLT is a *transformation* language. It takes one XML document and produces another. It uses XPath to select values and Michael posted the snippet that will select the values you want. What do you want as the *output* though?

Comment: The `desired output` you posted is what Michael's answer provides. And yet you said there that you want `<Payment>AMEX, AMEX</Payment>`, *not* just `AMEX, AMEX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in the context of `PackingNote`, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Header[1]/text()"/>
```

will return:

```
AMEX, AMEX
```

---

If you're in the context of `Header`, then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it wont work. Could you help me to add the amex values in payment . e.g <Payment>AMEX,AMEX</Payment> . it will be easier for me to get the value then.

Comment: @Techgeeks1 that's not what you asked for in the question though.

Comment: "won't work" is not a good description of a problem. Please edit your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: @Techgeeks1 you didn't post the desired output. It's clearly not `AMEX, AMEX`. Do you expect a different `<Payment>` element for each header? That would return *two* `Payment` elements. Or only the first?

Comment: @Techgeeks1 Your question still shows an XSLT snippet taken out of context. XSLT is very context-dependent. You can see my answer working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38Zv

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please attach your comments on the question to the question itself, not to my answer.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am working in header template. Let me show you complete xslt. Please see the edit

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm answering to the OP's comments in this answer. Commenting out of context in the question would make little sense either for the OP or anyone else trying to understand what's going on

Comment: That's (still) not a **complete** XSLT. Anyway, from the context of `Header`, the instruction `<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>` will return the required value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're not helping.